# Using control break logic in XSLT

Tags: variables, xslt

If have an XSLT that I need to modify to include control break logic and assumed I would just use the  element to do this until I discovered this limitation expressed on the w3schools site:

***Note: Once you have set a variable's value, you cannot change or modify that value!***

So what is an appropriate way to identify when a key value has changed? Here's the essence of what I'm trying to do:

```
<xsl:variable name="ctlBreakVar"/>

<xsl:for-each select="payment">

  <!-- Compare ctlBreakVar variable against referenceNumber value in payment record
       and if changed from previous payment, output something
  -->

</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input XML?

Comment: I really don't see how that's helpful as it's such a generic question, but here's a snippet:

  `<payment>
    <referenceNumber>150001</referenceNumber>
    <amount>770.55</amount>
  </payment>
  <payment>
    <referenceNumber>150001</referenceNumber>
    <amount>880.66</amount>
  </payment>
  <payment>
    <referenceNumber>150002</referenceNumber>
    <amount>4500.00</amount>
  </payment>`

I just need to do something different each time I encounter a new referenceNumber value.

Comment: Thanks for that. Examples of input XML are generally helpful with XSLT questions because they help clear up ambiguity. For example, what do you mean by "key value" in this case? Is `referenceNumber` an element or an attribute? Also, examples provide people with something they can test their solution against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, variables may not be modified in XSLT.  Do not think in terms of setting a variable to reflect the last seen `referenceNumber`.  Think instead in terms of a test that can be applied to the input document.  For each of your `payments`, you can test whether the earlier `payment` has the same `referenceNumber`.  For example...

**This XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/payments">
    <xsl:for-each select="payment">
      <xsl:variable name="curReferenceNumber" select="referenceNumber"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::payment[referenceNumber = $curReferenceNumber]">
          Same reference number.
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          Different reference number.
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**For this input XML:**

```
<payments>
  <payment>
    <referenceNumber>150001</referenceNumber>
    <amount>770.55</amount>
  </payment>
  <payment>
    <referenceNumber>150001</referenceNumber>
    <amount>880.66</amount>
  </payment>
  <payment>
    <referenceNumber>150002</referenceNumber>
    <amount>4500.00</amount>
  </payment>
</payments>
```

**Will produce this output:**

> ```
>       Different reference number.
>
>       Same reference number.
>
>       Different reference number.
> ```

Comment: This solution works with the example and is fine if `referenceNumber` elements are always grouped together (as seems reasonable). However, if you have `referenceNumber` elements in the order "150001, 150001, 150002, 150001" then the last one will not trigger the "Different reference number" message, as it has already appeared earlier.

Comment: I really didn't mean to sound critical. In fact, as well as comment on your answer I also upvoted it as I believe it's probably fine for the OP's purposes. However, to my reading, **previous** payment means the one *immediately* before this one, and I wanted to point that out just in case it was important.

Comment: Just to clarify, in my case the assumption is that matching referenceNumbers will always be contiguous as opposed to scattered throughout the XML input file. Ben's suggestion was easy enough and worked for me. I did, however, learn that the initial attempted tweak I made...

<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::payment[referenceNumber != $curReferenceNumber]">

...didn't work because the first record did not satisfy the condition of being a "different referenceNumber". So I had to first test for equality (as he did) and do nothing if true and put the rest of my code in the otherwise block.

Answer (score 3):

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/payments">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="payment"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Matches payment elements with the same reference number as the first preceding sibling payment element. -->
  <xsl:template match="payment[preceding-sibling::payment[1]/referenceNumber = current()/referenceNumber]">
    Same reference number.
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- All other payment elements, including the very first one. -->
  <xsl:template match="payment">
    Different reference number.
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input XML:

```
<payments>
  <payment>
    <referenceNumber>150001</referenceNumber>
    <amount>770.55</amount>
  </payment>
  <payment>
    <referenceNumber>150001</referenceNumber>
    <amount>880.66</amount>
  </payment>
  <payment>
    <referenceNumber>150002</referenceNumber>
    <amount>4500.00</amount>
  </payment>
</payments>
```

produces the following output XML:

```
    Different reference number.

    Same reference number.

    Different reference number.
```

Comment: I see your point, given I used the same string output. I just did that for easy comparison of the two stylesheets. My apologies. However, I disagree that I have only made minor alterations - the structures of our solutions are totally different (your use of `xsl:choose` versus my template matches).

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate solution in XSLT is to treat your payments as a population to be grouped by common values.  Then XSLT provides you everything you need without having pedestrian concerns about changing variable values.

There is no "break" in a for-each loop, because you are instructing to processor to visit every item addressed in the for-each select expression.  If you don't want to visit every one, then just address the ones you want.

Since you want the ones that are the first in document order of every group with common values, then use one of the many grouping methods.  In XSLT 2.0 that is `<xsl:for-each-group>`.

There are plenty of examples of this.